# How to find all combinations of numbers summing up to a certain number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A sum is given, for example 25, and numbers are given, for example 2, 5, 10
You need to find all the combinations for choosing this amount.
That is, the program should output 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5, 5 + 5 + 5 + 10, 5 + 10 + 10, 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 10 + 5 and so on.

What algorithms / methods / libraries do you recommend using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools` to get all the combinations, then keep only those that sum up to 25. I used `with_replacement` because the same value can come twice. Also, I used the flooring division because no number can come more often than the smallest one.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

candidates = list()

for i in range(25//2):  # floor division of largest by smallest
    candidates.extend(list(combinations_with_replacement([2, 5, 10], i)))

positive_cases = [i for i in candidates if sum(i) == 25]
```

```
[(5, 10, 10), (5, 5, 5, 10), 
 (5, 5, 5, 5, 5), (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 10), 
 (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5), 
 (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5)]
```

Comment: Might be worth explaining why you use `combinations_with_replacement` instead of `combinations`. There is a distinct difference between the two.

Comment: the option is good for this case, but if the amount is increased, for example, to 1000, then a "MemoryError" error will occur. And this is not to mention the possibility of increasing the number of operands

Comment: then i suggest you try it with the `yield` statement instead so it's not all in memory

Answer (score 0):

The number is the coefficient of x^25 in 1/((1-x^2)(1-x^5)(1-x^10))

So, [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) is your friend.

You can also do this using dynamic programming.